# javascript - check if array contains any of another array of strings

Tags: javascript

```
strings_to_check = ["a", "b", "c"]

test_arrrays = [ [ "a", "c", "e", "g"], [ "v", "x", "y", "z"] ]
```

What is the right way to check if each array in `test_arrays` contains `any` of the strings in `strings_to_check` array - ie. `a, b or c`

I could do the following, but it has its downside that even if one of the strings is present, it still check's for the rest.

```
for(let i = 0; i < test_arrrays.length; i++){
  for(let j = 0; j < strings_to_check.length; j++){
      if(test_arrrays[i].indexOf(strings_to_check[j]) > -1) {
          console.log("matched");
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: `let test = test_arrays.every(a => a.some(s => strings_to_check.includes(s)));`.

Answer (score 2):

This can be much more simply done with higher order functions, instead of devolving to using for loops and a slew of indices.

1. We want to see if all `test_arrrays` elements meet some criteria, so we know we should use `every`:

   ```
   test_arrrays.every(/* some criteria */);
   ```
2. Now we just have to find out what that criteria is. "contains any of the strings in strings_to_check" Sounds like we need to use `some` on `test_array`, to find out if any of its strings are contained in `strings_to_check`. So our "criteria" will be:

   ```
   test_arrray => test_arrray.some(s => strings_to_check_set.includes(s))
   ```

   putting it together, we get:

   ```
   test_arrrays.every( test_arrray => 
       test_arrray.some(s => strings_to_check_set.includes(s))
     )
   ```
3. `includes` has linear time complexity, so we can improve this algorithm by using a `Set`, and replacing `includes` with `has`, which has constant time complexity., to obtain this final result:

   ```
   strings_to_check = ["a", "b", "c"]

   test_arrrays = [ [ "a", "c", "e", "g"], [ "v", "x", "y", "z"] ]

   strings_to_check_set = new Set(strings_to_check)

   test_arrrays.every(test_arrray =>
       test_arrray.some(s => strings_to_check_set.has(s))
   )
   ```

Comment: Unfortunately your function returns a wrong result.

Comment: @Kinduser username checks out. Does it? What was your test case?

Comment: I guess you should replace your first `some` function with `every`, because as for now, it will return `true` even if **only one** array fulfills the condition (contains any item from `strings_to_check` array).

Comment: @Kinduser Oh, I misunderstood the question. Fixing it now

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to check if **every** array from `test_arrays` contains at least one element from the `strings_to_check` array, you could use mix of `Array#every` and `Array#some` functions.

```js
var strings_to_check = ["a", "b", "c"],
    test_arrrays = [ [ "a", "c", "e", "g"], [ "v", "x", "y", "z"] ],
    res = test_arrrays.every(v => v.some(c => strings_to_check.indexOf(c) > -1));
    
    console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple `test_arrrays`, it makes sense to convert the `strings_to_check` into a `Set` for constant time lookup. The overall time complexity then reduces from O(m n) to O(m + n log n) where n is the number of elements in `strings_to_check` and m is the total number of elements in all `test_arrrays` and O(n log n) is the `Set` setup time.

A generic `check` function would then look as follows:

```js
// Check if each haystack contains at least one needle:
function check(needles, haystacks) {
  needles = new Set(needles);
  return haystacks.every(haystack => haystack.some(element => needles.has(element)));
}

// Example:
console.log(check(
  ["a", "b", "c"],
  [["a", "c", "e", "g"], ["v", "x", "y", "z"]]
));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to match one string just add `break` just like this :

```
for(/*loop settings*/){
  /*some code*/
  for(/*loop settings*/){
    /*some code*/
    if(/*some conditional statement*/){
      /*handling stuff*/
      break;
    }
  }
}
```